# Adding a custom query argument to a custom taxonomy term page

Tags: wordpress, taxonomy, custom-taxonomy

I have a custom taxonomy created and I'm trying to add a new query argument with add_query_arg(), but it's not recognizing it at all when I visit the URL of a term of that taxonomy, with a query in the URL

for example, for a playlist taxonomy and the "edm" term and this URL:

http://someurl.com/playlist/edm/?some_variable=abc

some_variable is not recognized at all

When I use this code, to show all the query vars:

```
global $wp_query;
print_r($wp_query->query_vars);
```

some_variable doesn't exist, at all. It's like it doesn't see it at all!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to implement a hook somewhere in your plugin or theme so that WP is aware of your new variable.

```
public function my_plugin_add_query_vars($vars) {
    $vars[] = "some_variable";

    return $vars;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! That was it :-)